# Embeded google street view

Tags: google-maps, panoramas

Is it possible to have a google map embeded street view panorama of a given address in your page?

All the codes I have came across work with coordination, I'm looking for "address", since if you just use coordination you will have to set pov and all that,

Google seems to do that itself, look at the panorama picture here:

http://maps.google.ca/maps/place?hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=10&gs_id=z&xhr=t&biw=1680&bih=874&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=toyota+calgary&fb=1&gl=ca&hq=toyota&hnear=0x537170039f843fd5:0x266d3bb1b652b63a,Calgary,+AB&cid=16440335169618939517&ei=VpqYTpPsLbCrsALi0LnqBA&sa=X&oi=local_result&ct=map-marker-link&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CF8QrwswAA

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the [Google Maps Javascript API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). Take a look here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#StreetView

You can also embed Street View on your page by just using Google Maps.

1. Search for the address on Google Maps.
2. Go to the Street View for the location.
3. Click the link button in the upper-right hand corner above the map.
4. Click the 'Customize and preview embedded map' link.

A new page will open up with some customization opens and the code to embed the map/image on your page.

Comment: Thank you Casey but that's not what I was looking for I'm looking for a way to do that grammatically. The main challenge here is that the panorama options heading pitch and zoom need to be set manually, I was wondering if there is a way for google to find that out automatically by looking at the address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. All you need is a google decoder who will decode your address. Another way is to directly pass your address as a part of the url to google.
When using decoder, you will get the result in the form of a latitude longitude object which you can use to reset/set your map's marker

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accurately set the **heading** automatically and no way to set the **pitch** and **fov** (field of view) - BUT if you figure these out manually you can create a URL that fetches a static image with those settings from Google

Take a look at this tutorial on the [Street View Image API](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/42)